# Resizable table columns with jQuery (table wider than page)

Tags: jquery, html

I'm looking for a relatively simple solution to allow table column resizing. There's a similar question:

[Resizable table columns with jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6156182/resizable-table-columns-with-jquery)

I really like the simple solution; `jsfiddle.net/ydTCZ/`

But it doesn't work on my table (it seems to be because the table is wider than the screen). If i simplify my table to just a couple of columns it works fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cracked it.

The contents of my column headers `<th>`s are links (`<a>`s).

Instead of doing anything with the `<th>` I had to set the style of the `<a>`s to `display: block`

Then just `$('th a').resizable({handles:'e'});`

I should note I have both jQuery and jQuery UI loaded. JSFiddle example; http://jsfiddle.net/u32a1ccL/